# LINQ to Entities returns wrong ID for an entity's child's child

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a table structure in MySql, set up with foreign keys:

> Period { Id, Title }
>
> Activity { Id, Title, PeriodId }
>
> Resource { Id, FileName }
>
> ActivityResources { ActivityId, ResourceId }

This is set up with LINQ-to-Entities and I have checked that the table mappings are correct incuding the many-to-many relationship. Normally all works well with the `Period`, `Activity` and `Resource` classes.

However, I am trying to use this code:

```
private string ListAttachments(Ctx ctx) {
  var resList = new StringBuilder();
  var p = ctx.Periods.Include("Activities.Resources").Single(o => o.Id == 1);
  foreach (var a in p.Activities) foreach (var r in a.Resources)
    resList.Append(r.Id).Append(" - ").Append(r.FileName);
  return resList.ToString();
}
```

But it doesn't write the `Resource.Id` for each resource as expected; for some reason it writes the `Activity.Id` instead (though the `FileName` is correct).

Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT**

By the way, this works fine - but I'm still interested in the probem in the above code.

```
private string ListAttachments(Ctx ctx) {
  var resList = new StringBuilder();
  var res = ctx.Resources.Where(r => r.LessonActivities.Any(l => l.LessonId == 1)).ToList();
  foreach (var r in res) resList.Append(r.Id).Append(" - ").Append(r.FileName);
  return resList.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So, it's writing the activity.id instead of resource.id?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference a child/child collections that way. The `Activities` navigation property on a `Period` object is a collection. And you can't reference a property that belongs to an instance of an object via a collection of those objects.

Put another way, `Period p` has an `Activities` collection. But a collection of type `Activity` does **not** have a `Resources` collection. Only a single `Activity` has a `Resources` collection.

What I don't understand is why the first snippet works at all.

Anyway, to get to the `Resources` collection directly from a `Period`, you would need to use `SelectMany()`. Something like

```
List<Resource> resources = ctx.Periods
                              .Where(p=>p.Id == 1)
                              .SelectMany(p=>p.Activities)
                              .SelectMany(a => a.Resources)
                              .ToList();
```